# Recursive function without loop

Tags: java, loops, recursion

I have a problem  want to solve. I have an array of integers from which I want to get the minimum integer. I have also been given a function definition which am supposed to adhere to. I am not supposed to use a loop or a static variable in my solution. How can I solve this? Here is my function.

```
public static int findMin(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex){}
```

Please assist. I have tried this implementation with a loop.

```
public static int findMin(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    int min = 0;
    for (int count = startIndex; count <= endIndex; count++) {
        if (numbers[count] < min) {
            min = numbers[count];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: I will put here solution for Java 8 using streams. Just in case: `Arrays.asList(numbers).stream().min(Integer::compareTo).get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should consider when using recursion is the exit state; which means when the function will be exit

```
 public static int findMin(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        if(startIndex == endIndex){
            return numbers[startIndex];
        }
        int min = findMin(numbers, startIndex+1, endIndex);
        return  numbers[startIndex] < min ? numbers[startIndex] : min ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
int min(int a[]){ //Here you only need to supply the array.
    return min(a, 0, a[0]);
}

int min(int[] a, int i, int min)
{
    if(i==a.length-1)
        return  (a[i]<min)?a[i]:min;
    else
        return min(a, i+1, (a[i]<min)?a[i]:min);
}
```