# Get count from array using recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I need to get the count of numbers less than the first integer in an array using recursion. I am given a function definition as

```
public static int countGreaterThanFirst(int[]
numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex, int firstNumber){}
```

I am not supposed to use a loop or global/static variable. How can I convert my implementation below to satisfy the two conditions above. I have recently asked [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285176/recursive-function-without-loop/36285677#36285677) similar question but this is a bit different due to the need to keep track of the count variable. If someone can help, I will really appreciate. 
Below is my implementation with a loop.

```
public static int countGreaterThanFirst(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex, int firstNumber) {
    int greater_than_first = 0;
    for (int count = startIndex; count <= endIndex; count++) {
        if (numbers[count] > firstNumber) {
            greater_than_first++;
        }
    }
    return greater_than_first;
}
```

Comment: It works, but that's not the expected implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you don't need that much parameters:

```
public static int countGreaterThanFirst(int[] numbers, int currentIndex) {
    if (currentIndex == numbers.length) return 0;
    else {
        if (numbers[currentIndex] > numbers[0]) {
            return 1 + countGreaterThanFirst(numbers, currentIndex + 1);
        } else {
            return countGreaterThanFirst(numbers, currentIndex + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

and you should invoke it with (for example):

```
 countGreaterThanFirst(someArray, 1);
```

---

If you meant to find "all the numbers between `numbers[startIndex]` and `numbers[endIndex]` that are greater than `firstNumber`, then the implementation should be pretty similar to the above one:

```
public static int countGreaterThanFirst(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex, int firstNumber) {
    if (startIndex > endIndex) return 0;
    else {
        if (numbers[startIndex] > firstNumber) {
            return 1 + countGreaterThanFirst(numbers, startIndex + 1, endIndex, firstNumber);
        } else {
            return countGreaterThanFirst(numbers, startIndex + 1, endIndex, firstNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The parameters is a condition.

Comment: Yes, and I have to implement the function as per the definition given

Comment: unfortunately, the count is always 0.

Comment: How do you invoke it? Why don't you try to debug it at the least? It works fine on my environment.

Comment: @ Konstantin thanks for your help. It is working. I was invoking it wrongly.

Comment: Cold you please help with another?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int doCount(int[] list) {
    if (list.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + doCount(Arrays.copyOfRange(list, 1, list.length));
}
```